# Reusable React Map Method for Different Selected Arrays

Tags: reactjs

I have two simple methods - an Object.Key method and a map method in a React App. The Object.keys method populates a table header with keys from an array and the map method provides the values from the array in the body of the table. The Object.keys method does this without having to provide info about the keys whereas the map method requires the keys be provided(name,type).

I would like to know if there is a way of writing a map method without the need of providing these key values so that the map method can be reusable in the case another array is selected with different keys and values. Here is my code:

```
Here is the state:
...
this.state = { stars: {name:"Sirius,type:"AIVM"},{name:"Vega",type"AOV"}
   //example of another array which could be used: {planets: {planet_name:"Jupiter",number"5"}, etc...
```

Here are the Object.keys method and map method:

```
  tableHeadFunc=()=>{
    let headerKey = Object.keys(this.props.data[0])
    return(
      <thead>
       <tr>
         {headerKey.map((x,y)=>(  
           <th key={y}>
             {x}
           </th>
         ))}
       </tr>
      </thead>
    )
  }
...
  tableBodyFunc=()=>{
    return(
      <tbody>
       {this.props.data.map((x,y)=> (
         <tr key={y}>
           <td>{x.name}</td>
           <td>{x.type}</td>
         </tr>
       ))}
       </tbody>
    )
  }
```

I have tried several times to write the map method using different methods, such as  Object.values() and Object.entries() but so far haven't been able to come up with a solution.

Comment: What is props.data?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do the following (not sure what data is in props):

```js
function App() {
  const data = [
    { name: 'Sirius1', type: 'AIVM' },
    { name: 'Sirius2', type: 'AIVM' },
  ];
  //assuming all items in data are objects with same keys
  const keys = Object.keys(data[0]);
  return (
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          {/* keys in Object.keys are unique, no need to use index */}
          {keys.map(key => (
            <th key={key}>{key}</th>
          ))}
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        {data.map((item, index) => (
          //if you use index as key then make sure you never delete or sort the data
          <tr key={index}>
            {/* use the same keys as used in header */}
            {keys.map(key => (
              <td key={key}>{item[key]}</td>
            ))}
          </tr>
        ))}
      </tbody>
    </table>
  );
}


//render app
ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```